# How can I use fetch on a strapi table to return only records that match two fields?

Tags: javascript, strapi

I have a table, "bond", with two fields, projid and userid, both integer. I would like to use fetch or axios to return a record where projid = 3 and userid=10, for example. I want to provide these two values and I should get back a single record or none.

I have the following backend function

```
export async function getBond(uid, pid) {
  const urlx = `${url}/api/bonds`
  const response = await fetch(urlx)
  const data = response.json()
  return data
}
```

This returns ALL records and I could filter from this point based on the two field values, but wanted to get an answer in one step. Is it possible?

I tried adding ?projid=${pid}&userid=${uid} to the url as I saw something similar in Strapi docs but this still returns ALL records. If I hard code something invalid like ?projid=999&userid=876 (invalid because I do not have such values in any records) it still returns ALL records.

Im using Strapi 4.4.1.

Comment: Also tried adding parameters via searchParams.append but still get all records returned, as if Strapi is ignoring all parameters.

Comment: `projid` and `userid` both these fields exists in your bond schema, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using the REST API via `/api/bonds?filters[projid]=3&filters[userid]=10`

Feel free to read more on how filtering works on the [strapi docs](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/filtering-locale-publication.html#filtering).